# Testing REST API controller in PHP with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, phpunit

I have a very small test suite for testing CRUD operations on a REST API. My controller displays a form, table, etc, based on the information provided by the API. My test class create a new [Buzz](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/) object and makes requests to the API server.

Unfortunately, this sucks, because if i update or delete something, it is deleted in the API. This is a very bad test practice. How can i unit test my application, when using an external data source like this?

Answer (score 1):

Look into test doubles and stubs in the PHPUnit docs:

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

You can use them to replace API functionality.

Comment: Thing is, i cannot mock the server response. I would have to mock the response, based on the request, making sure both are OK.

Comment: It's just a simple Buzz usage: submitting GETs and POSTs with data to be created, updated or deleted. The problem is: i don't want to interact with the service database/logic, i just want to make sure my client is communicating well.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, this sucks, because if i update or delete something, it
>   is deleted in the API. This is a very bad test practice. How can i
>   unit test my application, when using an external data source like
>   this?

Create some fake, erasable data.. matter of fact you should be not even running PHPUnit tests on a production database/server.